# How to trim in JSON the miliseconds in DateTime serialization

Tags: c#, json, datetime, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WEB API 2 call, with Entity Framework. If I update a `DateTime` column from my entity that I read from the database with `DateTime.Now`, and I serialize it to the client, the column with `DateTime` that I received from the database has 3 numbers for the milliseconds, but the column with `DateTime` that I updated in the C# code has 6 digits. Below is the C# code in my controller:

```
[Route("{id:long}/updatedatetime", Name = "UpdateDateTimeByID")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(ClGroup))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateDateTimeByID(int id)
{
        ClGroup clGroup = await db.ClGroups.FindAsync(id);
        if (clGroup == null)
        {
        return NotFound();
        }
        clGroup.DtUpdate = DateTime.Now;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        var groupReturn = mapper.Map<ClGroupModel>(clGroup);
        return Ok(groupReturn);
}
```

Below is the JSON that is serialized back to the client

```
{
  "CdGroup": 1,
  "NmGroup": "Grupo 1",
  "DcGroup": "Primeiro Grupo",
  "DtInsert": "2016-07-03T22:18:52.257",
  "DtUpdate": "2016-07-12T13:31:08.2882558",
  "IdStatus": true
}
```

Is there a way so that the `DtUpdate` is serialized with 3 digits as well?
I changed the formatter with the configuration below:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;
json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) and set the `DateFormatString` property on it like this:

```
var dateConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter 
{ 
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'" 
};
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);
```

The lowercase `fff` ensures the milliseconds portion is always exactly 3 digits long.  In contrast, the [default format](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs#L37) uses uppercase `FFFFFFF` for the milliseconds, which includes up to seven digits of precision, but omits trailing zeros.  This is why you are seeing varying lengths for the milliseconds.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) in the .NET Framework documentation for more info on custom date formats.